# Process data and continue if NULL

Tags: c#, object, process, null

I have to process a number of items of data for example

```
User u = NotMyObject.GetUser(100);
ProcessProperty(u.FirstName);
ProcessProperty(u.Surname);
ProcessProperty(u.Phone.Work);
ProcessProperty(u.Phone.Mobile);
...
ProcessProperty(u.Address.PostCode);
```

Take it that all properties are returned from GetUser(...) as string. What ProcessProperty does is, I hope, not relevant (maybe write the value to a file, for example) but it would look like:

```
private void ProcessProperty(string data) {
...
}
```

My question is given that u.Phone & likewise u.Address may be NULL how can I process the "User u" object without putting each ProcessProperty(...) call in a try/catch block?

Apologies if the formatting of the question is no good, I'm still getting the hang of posting.

Many thanks. N.

Comment: Does `ProcessProperty` raises an exception when data is null?

Comment: @sll: if u.Phone is null, when you try to access its Work property it should throw an exception...

Comment: I don't understand. You write *Take it that all properties are returned from GetUser(...) as string*. Then you access `u.Phone.Work`. Your previous statement indicates that `Phone` should be a string. Or is it in fact so that the properties exposed by `User` can be of any type, but we will only pass strings to `ProcessProperty`?

Comment: Indeed, `string` does not expose `Work`, `Mobile`, nor `PostCode` properties.

Comment: Indeed it does throw an exception if u.Phone is null and I try to access u.Phone.Work...._Take it that all **FINAL** properties are returned from GetUser(...) as string_

Comment: **Thanks to everyone, I think there's plenty to get me sorted here.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try (maybe it's not elegant):

```
ProcessProperty(u.Phone == null ? null : u.Phone.Work);
```

and

```
private void ProcessProperty(string data) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) {
        ....
    } else {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the straight-forward way to go, and when I have more time I'll look at the moand stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the User class I would change the Set code on the properties wich can be null to convert NULL to String.Empty

Answer (score 0):

if you have control of the ProcessProperty function then you can just add this inside the function

```
if(data == null) return;
```

otherwise you can just write this

```
if(u.Phone != null)
     ProcessProperty(u.Phone.Work);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda expressions and an extension method to make a maybe monad:

```
public static class ObjectExt
{
    public static TProp GetPropOrNull<TObj, TProp>(this TObj obj, 
        Func<User,TProp> getProp)
        where TObj : class
        where TProp : class
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        else
            return getProp(obj);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
u.GetPropOrNull(obj => obj.Phone).GetPropOrNull(obj => obj.Work);
u.GetPropOrNull(obj => obj.Phone).GetPropOrNull(obj => obj.Home);
```

Instead of using a long dot chain (like u.Phone.Work.Whatever) which fails if any of the first properties are null, this method short-circuits and returns null as soon as it sees a null. This can shorten your code by a great deal (as opposed to using if-checks) if you have to work with a property deep down in someone else's class who maybe isn't a very careful programmer. I think in the article below, the author uses the method name `With` instead of `GetPropOrNull`, so that even shortens it up further.

**Reference:**

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/maybemonads.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you CAN'T change **ProcessProperty** consider wrapping it:

```
private void ProcessPropertySafe(string data) 
{
    if (data != null)
    {
        ProcessProperty(data);
    }
}
```

or do it like int.Parse() vs. int.TryParse():

```
private bool TryProcessProperty(string data) 
{
    try
    {
        ProcessProperty(data);
        return true;
    }
    catch // <- That's not clean ...
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Better name for ProcessPropertyWrapper is ProcessPropertySafe